# How to get minion id from jinja script inside a salt state

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I need to apply a if-else logic based on a static minion id inside a state file. The target glob qualifies a whole bunch of servers, but I need to run a small piece of logic on a single server and run a bunch of common things on all of them. How can I do this?

When I put this in a Jinja file, its errors:

```
{% import salt.config %}
{% minion_opts = salt.config.minion_config('/etc/salt/minion') %}
{% print(minion_opts['id']) %}
{% if minion_opts['id'] == 'xyz.server': %}
-- run the logic here
..
..
```

Error:

```
- Rendering SLS 'base:bin.test' failed: Jinja syntax error: expected token 'as', got 'end of statement block'; line 1  
-  
- ---  
- {% import salt.config %}    <======================  
- {% minion_opts = salt.config.minion_config('/etc/salt/minion') %}  
- {% print(minion_opts['id']) %}
```

It probably goes without saying I am not a Saltstack expert by any means.

Comment: where does your code end and the error start? could you fix formatting?

Comment: What's being shown above is the beginning and it fails at the first line itself. Its not liking the import statement. But its described as legal in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

So first off, I realize this is an old question, but it still shows up at the top of the my search results for both DDG and Google for a somewhat related problem and the current answers don't really deliver on the ask, so here's an answer based off the latest SaltStack version (3002):

In order to get control flow working for Jinja based off minion id:

```
{% if salt['grains.get']('id') == 'minion_a' %}
some text to render for minion_a
{% else %}
some text to render otherwise
{% endif %}
```

I realize there were other issues in how the question was phrased and for the sample code provided, but my code snippet answers the actual question of:

> I need to apply a if-else logic based on a static minion id inside a state file.

> How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're using Jinja's `import` in an [unexpected way](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#import).  If this is a Flask app, you should use something like this in your views.py route to provide variables to the template:

```
render_template('my_template.html', salt=salt)
```

The corrected code should look something like this:

```
{% set minion_opts = salt.config.minion_config('/etc/salt/minion') %}
{{ minion_opts['id'] }}
{% if minion_opts['id'] == 'xyz.server' %}
  {{ 'logic goes here' }}
{% endif %}
```

See the [Assignments docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments) on how to assign values to variables.

No colon is necessary at the end of the [`if` statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#if), and remember to use `{% endif %}` after you're done with your conditional statements.

Comment: The python code I pasted above is simply what I am trying to put inside a salt state. Salt states allow for jinja python. You can find the example here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/

Comment: @SridharNallani While visually-similar, Jinja isn't Python.  Have you tried the Salt Jinja docs?  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html

Comment: Hi @Roundel, your answer isn't very specific. Yes, I am using jinja in a consistent way shown in the links both you and me pasted. If you can point out exactly whats the issue in this code or what I should do differently, that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: The error message you received, plus the Jinja docs I linked are sufficient.  You're using Jinja's `import` incorrectly; it expects something like `import 'foo.html' as bar`.  Once that's fixed, you'll then be able to see how the rest of your code fares.